# Need jQuery function to close open div while opening new one

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I'm using the following code to open a `DIV` container on my home page. It works great but it's a little clunky because you have to close (x) out the open `DIV` before you can open another one. I have three on a page. Ideally, if I have `DIV#A` open, and I click on button B to open `DIV#B`, I'd like to have `DIV#A` close and `DIV#B` open at once.

Can anyone help?

This is my JavaScript:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    // click trigger for popup 1
    $("a.topopup").click(function () {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, delay in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 100); // .5 second
        $("#toPopup_2, #toPopup_3").hide();

        return false;
    });
    // click trigger for popup 2
    $("a.topopup_2").click(function () {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, delay in .5 second
            loadPopup_2(); // function show popup 
        }, 100); // .5 second
        $("#toPopup, #toPopup_3").hide();
        return false;
    });
    // click trigger for popup 3
    $("a.topopup_3").click(function () {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, delay in .5 second
            loadPopup_3(); // function show popup 
        }, 100); // .5 second
        return false;
        $("#toPopup, #toPopup_2").hide();
    });

    /* event for close the popup */
    $("div.close").hover(

    function () {
        $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
    },

    function () {
        $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
    });

    $("div.close").click(function () {
        disablePopup(); // function close pop up
    });

    $(this).keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
            disablePopup(); // function close pop up
        }
    });

    $("div#backgroundPopup").click(function () {
        disablePopup(); // function close pop up
    });

    $('a.livebox').click(function () {
        alert('Hello World!');
        return false;
    });


    /************** start: functions. **************/
    function loading() {
        $("div.loader").show();
    }

    function closeloading() {
        $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');
    }

    var popupStatus = 0; // set value

    // load popup 1
    function loadPopup() {
        if (popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }
    }
    // load popup 2
    function loadPopup_2() {
        if (popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup_2").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }
    }
    // load popup 2
    function loadPopup_3() {
        if (popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup_3").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }
    }

    // function close popups
    function disablePopup() {
        if (popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup

            $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
            $("#toPopup_2").fadeOut("normal");
            $("#toPopup_3").fadeOut("normal");

            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
            popupStatus = 0; // and set value to 0
        }
    }

    /************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End
```

This is how I'm calling it from my page:

```html
<div id="popupcontainer">
    <div id="toPopup">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div id="popup_content">Content 1 Goes Here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="toPopup_2">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div id="popup_content">Content 2 Goes Here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="toPopup_3">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <div id="popup_content">Content 3 Goes Here</div>
        <!--toPopup end-->
```

Comment: To get a better response you might want to trim down your JS, but also get a working copy of it on jsfiddle.net or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a LOT going on in your script here. Most noticeable is the abundance of code duplication. I condensed this down while doing what you wanted, having one click close open popups and then show the one that was clicked.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUcnH/4) for the complete HTML and javascript cahnges. Below is a summary of what I did:

Changed your ids for each popup to a common class (**EDIT** also changed id="popup_content" to a class. You cannot have duplicate ids on a page):

```
<div class="topopup">
    <div class="close">close</div>
    <div class="popup_content">Content 1 Goes Here</div>
</div>
<div class="topopup">
    <div class="close">close</div>
    <div class="popup_content">Content 2 Goes Here</div>
</div>
...
```

Next, I combined your separate functions into one. That is

```
$("a.topopup").click(function () {
    //...
    $("#toPopup_2, #toPopup_3").hide();
    //....
    return false;
});

$("a.topopup_2").click(function () {
    //...
    $("#toPopup, #toPopup_3").hide();
    //....
    return false;
});

//etc
```

to a single function of (**Edit**: You had a.topopup when it is in a div. Should be div.topopup):

```
$("div.topopup").click(function () {
    loading(); // loading

    //hide all open popups
    $(".topopup").hide();

    //show the popup and stuff
    var storedThis = this;
    setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, delay in .5 second
        loadPopup(storedThis);
    }, 100); // .5 second

    return false;
});
```

Lastly, you can similarly combine your 3 loadPopup() functions into

```
function loadPopup(popup) {
    closeloading(); // fadeout loading
    $(popup).fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
    $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
}
```

There is probably more to be done to clean things up, but this should get you started. The trick was getting all your popups in a common class so that they can all be treated the same and make your code reusable.

Comment: thanks so much! I just saw this answer Eric. I'll try this out and get right back with you...

Comment: I have made a few edits. If you have some errors, please look at my edits and try again. I have also updated the jsfiddle link for the complete changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eric and your tip Jamie. Here's my jsfiddle. This should better illustrate what I'm trying to do. When you click on one of the links, it opens up a colored-background div container, I need it so if you click on the other link, it opens up that div container so you don't have to unclick and then click again.

http://jsfiddle.net/bwilkins/dvk9f/

Comment: revised jquery script. only problem is flashing upon initial load. any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/bwilkins/dvk9f/28/

Comment: the flashing on load, I figured out had to do with css positioning. It's working great now!

Comment: Here is a cleaned up and working [jsfiddle.net/dvk9f/38](http://jsfiddle.net/dvk9f/38/) without the flashing you were experiencing. You were fading-in the next content while the previous was still fading-out and still "in the way". I placed the code to show the next content area inside a callback function which only runs after the fadeOut() from the previously visible content completes.

Comment: My solution above changed and condensed a lot of your code. A less intrusive solution would be [jsfiddle.net/dvk9f/39](http://jsfiddle.net/dvk9f/39/). Here I only changed the .fadeOut("nornmal") to .hide() in your disablePopup() function. You lose your fadeout effect, but looks visually nice still IMO.

Comment: Haha, did not realized you fixed it while I was. Well now you have a js option.